# No usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Project structure are as follows. (Visual Studio 2015 Community)

One static library project
One Console Application project

static library is created using default settings and linked to console application project. Program is working fine. But in release build of console application linked with static library following information is displayed.

> All 205 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
>
> Finished generating code
>
> ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

is there any problem while generating release static library using default options.

cannot understand why there is not ipdb/iobj files in static library build directories. Whereas there are ipdb/iobj files in console application build directories.

Every project(static/console app) are build with default settings.

static libs are in **C** and console application is in **C++**

In debug build no such information is show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not related to static library builds. Only executable builds have the LTCG:incremental option available. When building Console/Windows application there is no ipdb/iobj files so the information is displayed. After first build ipdb/iobj files are created. So no more info after that until rebuild is called. It is only information that LTCG with incremental option is enabled.

Answer (score 17):

The way to fix this is Visual Studio is to look at the library build options and change the linker options.

Linker --> Optimization -->
Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG:incremental)

**Remove the incremental in the linker options**

Linker --> Optimization -->
Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)

Situation: One library project One Windows Application project
Library is created using default settings and linked to windows application project. Program is working fine. But in release build of the library produces the same error as above.

Comment: Add it as a comment not an answer

Comment: Hello Ignacio, I tried to add a comment but the system would not permit me as I do not have enough reputation points. The system said I need 50 points to add a comment

Comment: the answer is not clear. no option Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)